# How to best UNLOAD content in a DIV using LOAD or HTML to manage resources?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.6.2.

In a master page, I open up several divs that will later be populated with info through the use of buttons:

```
<input type="button" id="ButtonOne">
<input type="button" id="ButtonTwo">
<input type="button" id="ButtonThree">
<div class="SectionDiv" id="DivOne"></div>
<div class="SectionDiv" id="DivTwo"></div>
<div class="SectionDiv" id="DivThree"></div>
```

I make a call to populate the divs like this:

```
$("#ButtonOne").click(function() {
    $("#DivOne").load("FileOne.html");
});
```

When I popule a div, I want to get rid of everything in the other divs.  I have done this two different ways.  Like this:

```
// METHOD ONE
$("#ButtonOne").click(function() {
    // UNLOAD ALL DIVS
    $(".SectionDiv").load("BlankPage.html");
    // LOAD THE DIV THAT NEEDS TO BE LOADED
    $("#DivOne").load("FileOne.html");
});

// METHOD TWO
$("#ButtonOne").click(function() {
    // UNLOAD ALL DIVS
    $(".SectionDiv").html("");
    // LOAD THE DIV THAT NEEDS TO BE LOADED
    $("#DivOne").load("FileOne.html");
});
```

In method one, I load the div with a page that has no content, a completely empty page. In method two, I use html("") with the same effect(?).

While these two methods have the same visual outcome, does one have a distinct advantage over the other for killing existing variables in the divs, or detaching elements better from the DOM, or anything?  Is one faster in certain environments than the other? Does one hog more resources than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method one causes a request to get the blank page for no reason (because you know it is blank, there is no need for a request). So essentially method two is the optimized version of method one because it saves the useless additional HTTP requests.

Comment: So, you are suggesting that LOAD uses more resources than HTML?

Comment: Yes, because `load` sends a HTTP request to get your blank page. Then it replaces the content of the `div` with the empty content (assuming `BlackPage.html` is really empty). Using `html` avoids the HTTP request because you do tell it what to insert without the need for a request. If you don't do the request, you don't need resources for it – thus `html` uses less resources. You might want to open your page in Firefox with Firebug enabled and watch the traffic (net tab) to see the requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. My page sped up noticeably after I made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".SectionDiv").each(function(index, ele){
ele.html("");
});
```

try the above, since there are more than one `.SectionDiv` element, you have to loop for each element.

Comment: There would be no point in doing this. $(".SectionDiv") works just fine at finding all of the section divs.